# Error in Mongoose Documentation? Model save() numberAffected 1 for update rather creation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Confused about Mongoose documentation.... It states for model.js save():

```
product.sold = Date.now();
product.save(function (err, product, numberAffected) {
  if (err) ..
})
```

> The callback will receive three parameters, err if an error occurred, product which is the saved product, and numberAffected which will be 1 when the document was found and updated in the database, otherwise 0.

When I insert a new document into my model/database I get numberAffected 1. But from the documentation, 1 would be if the document was found...wouldn't that mean a that document existed before and it would a update instead of a creation?

**To be clear, the documents that I create are always new, never pre-existing. There are never pre-existing documents that get updated instead of inserted. Yet, I get numberAffected 1**

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't, and the reason is that `.save()` is more of a convenience wrapper for `.update()` but including the "upsert" functionality. Think of it like this:

```
Model.update(
    { _id: obj._id }, 
    obj, 
    { upsert: true },
    function(err,numAffected) {

       return [err, obj, numAffected];
    }
)
```

Not exactly the implementation but it helps to visualize that way.

So the third parameter is the number affected but the "update" part and would be 0 if this resulted in a new document that was actually "upserted". Much like as is returned from the `.update()` method the value will be the number of documents affected by the update, but only where that "update" applied to an existing document.

Comment: How could I tell/get a return value to signal if the document existed and was updated or if a new one was created with model api save()?

Comment: @dman Much as already stated. If the numAffected value in the callback is 0 then the document was inserted. If not and 1 then it already existed.

Comment: I am not seeing it. My documents are always new and are inserted...never pre-existing documents that updated... but numberAffected 1 is returned.